# Converting boost::python::object to (non-const) lvalue

Tags: python, c++, templates, boost

So the question pertains to my chosen solution to my real problem, which, for the sake of giving as full of a picture as possible is this:  Basically I have a function with a lot of template parameters that I'm attempting to expose to Python.  As opposed to doing something nightmarish with macros to stamp out all the template parameter combinations that I need, I've been using `boost::python::object` for type-erasure, and then using `extract` to get the types I need out of it.

However, it doesn't seem possible to get a non-const lvalue out of `boost::python::extract`.  Here's a toy problem:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/python.hpp>

class Dog
{
public:
   void noise() { std::cout << "WOOF" << std::endl; }
};

class Cat
{
public:
   void noise() { std::cout << "MEOW" << std::endl; }
};

template< class Animal >
void make_noise(Animal & a)
   { a.noise(); }

//Wrapping for boost python
void make_noise_py(boost::python::object & a)
{
   {
      boost::python::extract<Dog> get(a);
      if(get.check())
      {
         Dog & d = get();
         make_noise(d);
      }
   }
   {
      boost::python::extract<Cat> get(a);
      if(get.check())
      {
         Cat & c = get();
         make_noise(c);
      }
   }
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(main)
{
   boost::python::def("make_noise", make_noise_py);
}
```

Note that while this problem has only one template parameter with two options, my actual problem has about 4 template parameters, usually with more than two options for each...so stamping each template out is out of the question, and using macros seems even more messy.  The only other option I can see is using const_cast, which I also like to avoid if I can help it.  I'd really like to just get a non-const lvalue from a `boost::python::object`, but I don't know how to do that.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
boost::python::extract<Dog>
```

you're getting back a `Dog`. If you want to then get an lvalue reference back, you'll need to construct the appropriate `extract` object:

```
boost::python::extract<Dog&>
```

---

Of course the more Python solution would be to just stay in the python realm. Something like:

```
void make_noise(boost::python::object o) {
    o.attr("noise")();
}
```

Comment: The first option doesn't work.  boost::python::extract<Dog&> get(o) will fail the next line (get.check()).

The second option I don't think is really applicable to me either.  For the purposes of this problem, make_noise is 3rd party code.  (It's not really but it's involved enough that I can't just go and re-implement the entire tree to work on boost::python::objects.) 

I might be able to create an animal_wrapper that wraps a boost::python::object though?  I might give that a shot, I never considered that approach.

Comment: @Hounddog Definitely works for me if you're actually passing in a `Dog`.

Comment: @Hounddog In fact, yours wouldn't even compile for me as you're trying to initialize an lvalue reference from a temporary...

Comment: Here's pastes of the exact code that I'm using (copy-paste):  main.cpp http://pastebin.com/9V0qLnD5, test.py http://pastebin.com/c8inTFmK.  I'm compiling with the following line:  g++ -shared -o main.so -lboost_python3 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -fPIC main.cpp.  I get the following output:  RuntimeError:  COULD NOT CONVERT.

Comment: There's font difficulties there, the character before boost_python3 is a lowercase L and the character before /usr is a capital i

Comment: This is using g++ 5.2.0, python 3.4.3 and boost 1.58.  Maybe they changed something in boost 1.59?

Comment: @Hounddog Because your `x` isn't a `Dog` instance, it's the `Dog` class. You need to write `main.Dog()` to create an instance.

Comment: ...that seems to work!  I wonder if that's what I was doing in my actual problem.  Checking real quick....

Comment: Yup, it seems to be working now, so that must have been my mistake I made earlier too.  That's what I get I guess for being a poor python programmer :-)  Thanks for the help!